# Why is sys.argv set to None on exit in Python?

Tags: python, cpython, internals

Please consider the following script:

```
import sys


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Constructing A')
        print(sys.argv)
        print(sys.meta_path)
        print(sys.float_info)

    def __del__(self):
        print('Destructing A')
        print(sys.argv)
        print(sys.meta_path)
        print(sys.float_info)


x = A()
```

What I would expect from running this code would be printing the same `sys.argv` in `__init__()` and `__del__()` of class `A`. However, the output is different than expected:

```
Constructing A
['test.py']
[<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, ...]
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, ...)

Destructing A
None
None
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, ...)
```

My question: why this happens? Is it an implementation detail that CPython sets `sys.argv` to `None` on shutdown, or is it described somewhere in the documentation? And why Python (either explicitly or by GC) first removes some objects from `sys` (like `argv` or `meta_path`), while keeping others (like `float_info`)?

I am using CPython 3.8.5 on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is Python's shutdown procedure documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649676/where-is-pythons-shutdown-procedure-documented)

Comment: Note that one CPython Python 3.7.4 on MacOS ``sys.float_info`` also is set ``None``.

Answer (score 5):

During the `__del__`s that occur during interpreter shutdown, all guarantees of the interpreter state are more or less off.

My educated guess is that modules and objects are getting cleaned up in an arbitrary order. If you feel like delving in, [`Py_FinalizeEx(void)` here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/daa0fe03a517d335d48e65ace8e5da636e265a8f/Python/pylifecycle.c#L1333-L1334) seems to be the relevant function that calls all the rest.

(You shouldn't rely on `__del__` for deterministic cleanup anyway; for instance, an user may have `gc.disable()`d and your function will never get called. Instead, use context managers.)