# imported modules becomes None when replacing current module in sys.modules using a class object

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import

an unpopular but "supported" python hack (see Guido: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-May/014969.html) that enables `__getattr__` usage on module attributes involves the following:

```
import os, sys

class MyClass(object):

    def check_os(self):
        print os

sys.modules[__name__] = MyClass()
```

On import, this the imported module becomes a class instance:

```
>>> import myModule
>>> myModule
<myModule.MyClass object at 0xf76def2c>
```

However, in Python-2.7, all other imported modules within the original module is set to None.

```
>>> repro.check_os()
None
```

In Python-3.4, everything works:

```
>>> repro.check_os()
<module 'os' from '/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/os.py'>
```

This feels like something to do with [Imported modules become None when running a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084260/imported-modules-become-none-when-running-a-function), but, anyone knows why this happens internally?

It seems that if you store the original module (without fully replacing it in Python-2) then everything continues to work:

```
sys.modules[__name__+'_bak'] = sys.modules[__name__]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you are running in to is that in Pythons prior to 3.4 when a module is destroyed (as yours is because you replace it with a class and there are no further references to it), the items in that module's `__dict__` are forcibly set to `None`.

The workaround, if you need to support Pythons prior to 3.4, is have an `import` statement in the class that will replace the module:

```
class MyClass(object):

    import os

    def check_os(self):
        print(os)
```

For more info, see [this answer about interpreter shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25649713/208880).