# Calling method of parent class when sys.modules[__name__] is altered (child class not available in global namespace)

Tags: python, sys, method-resolution-order

In module 1:

```
class Parent(object):
    def my_method(self):
        print 'Hello World'


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def my_method(self):
        # Do something
        super(Child, self).my_method()
        # Do something more


import sys
sys.modules[__name__] = Child(__name__)
```

In module 2:

```
import module1
module1.my_method()
```

Loading module2 fails.

Result:

```
File "c:\archive2\stack\module2.py", line 3, in <module>
  module1.my_method()
File "c:\archive2\stack\module1.py", line 12, in my_method
  super(Child, self).my_method()

TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not None
```

Looks like the value of variables Child and Parent is None when module2 is executed.

A similar problem was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765677/nested-classes-scope).  Is there a generic solution for accessing method of parent class when child class is not available in global namespace?

Comment: I tried, but I can't make this code "fail" (whatever that means, exactly). I don't see any reason why assigning an object into `sys.modules` should make your class stop working. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Aran-Fey:  I have edited with more details.  I believe now it can be reproduced.

Comment: It seems like you have a bug in the my_method function under the child class, should be : super(Parent, self).my_method()

Comment: @Rohi: No, it should be Parent.my_method(self) of super(Child, self).my_method()

Comment: @Rohi No, that's not how you use `super`. `super(Child, self)` is correct.

Comment: @VinayakKaniyarakkal Can you add the error message to your question, please?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rvcquhqm Seems like the value of variables Child and Parent is None at my_method when this code is executed.

Comment: Please [edit] it into the question. It makes your question better and makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [imported modules becomes None when replacing current module in sys.modules using a class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107470/imported-modules-becomes-none-when-replacing-current-module-in-sys-modules-using)

Comment: Your module is being garbage collected because you removed it from `sys.modules`. The easy workaround is to save a reference to the module before you overwrite it: `_ = sys.modules[__name__]; sys.modules[__name__] = Child(__name__)`. Also, this workaround isn't necessary upwards of python 3.4.